# null terminated character is not recognized

Tags: c++, winapi, null-terminated

I use the OPENFILENAME ofn way to open a browse file dialog in win32 application.

I want to be able to use dynamic the file filtering according to what user needs and not as predefined to all files

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"All Files\0*.*\0\0";
```

I tried to change the predefined code with a dynamic one but it seems that even the null-terminated character is treated as string in the below code

```
string UserChoice = "Exe Files\0*.exe\0\0";
wstring ChoiceTemp = s2ws(UserChoice); // convert string to lpcwstr
LPCWSTR FilterByUser = ChoiceTemp.c_str();
ofn.lpstrFilter = FilterByUser;
```

It seems that the \0 is not recognized as null character in the browse file dialog and it doesn't show any files at all, my knowledge on c++ is on my first steps and i can`t make it work without any help on this issue and i searched around the net but nothing came in handy.

Any suggestion on how to make it work ?

Comment: Why do you need these null-terminators? `std::string` doesn't need them. You can just assign a string to it and the null-terminator will be added automatically

Comment: @Force They are required by OPENFILENAME's API specification. NUL terminator characters are used as delimiters. Of course, the entire string is double-NUL terminated, so you could still use `std::string`, because it does support embedded NULs.

Comment: All of that code you've got there is rather pointless. If you want a wide string, just make one: `std::wstring UserChoice = L"EXE Files\0*.exe\0"`. Note, too, that string literals always have an implicit NUL terminator character, so the double `\0\0` at the end is unnecessary. Then you'd just do `ofn.lpstrFilter = UserChoice.c_str()`.

Comment: @panta rei: the \0 character between Exe Files and *.exe is needed for the browse file dialog to understnad what files needs to be filtered in the dialog.

Comment: @Cody Gray is doesn`t get the string value at once in the ofn.lpstrFilter("error a value of type const char cannot be assigned ... to LPCWSTR

Comment: ForceBru : the OP hasn't actually stated it, but `LPCWSTR` is a type (a `typedef` from memory) used within the windows API.   There are a number of windows API functions which require a set of strings to be passed with terminating zeros separating strings, and the last string being followed by a pair of zeros.

Comment: @CodyGray: `std::wstring UserChoice = L"EXE Files\0*.exe\0"` doesn't help. It gets truncated on construction, exhibiting the same issue the OP is experiencing. Removing the use of ANSI-encoded strings is still good advice.

Comment: Yeah, IInspectable is right, I missed that on first glance. You'll need to do as Joachim has already explained and use a constructor for `std::wstring` that takes an explicit length. The problem you're running into is that all Windows API functions require *wide* strings, and `std::string` is a narrow string. If you switch over to using `std::wstring` for everything, you won't have any problems calling API functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lpstrFilter` is usually a constant string so there is no need for `std::wstring`. Just define a constant string:

```
const wchar_t* filter = 
    L"All files\0*.*\0"
    L"Exe files\0*.exe\0";
```

But it can be done as follows if necessary (I am repeating @Joachim Pileborg)

```
std::wstring filter = 
    L"All files|*.*|"
    L"Exe files|*.exe|";
std::replace(filter.begin(), filter.end(), '|', '\0');
ofn.lpstrFilter = filter.data();
```

Use `filter.data()` instead of `c_str()`. To select a particular filter use `nFilterIndex`

```
wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy_s(filename, L"c:\\test\\default file.txt");

OPENFILENAME ofn = { sizeof(OPENFILENAME) };
ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
ofn.nFilterIndex = 2; //select "Exe files"
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings with embedded terminators, but you have to use the correct [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to create the string.

More specifically either the one where you explicitly specify a length (number 4 in the linked constructor reference) or a start and end iterator (number 6).  In this case, the first one is best:

```
string UserChoice("Exe Files\0*.exe\0", 16);
```

Comment: thanks for the link but my knowledge isn't so good but i dont write the definition, the definition of the Exe Files\0*.exe comes from user input that comes as a string and i just need to enter it as value in the ofn.lpstrFilter. Something i am doing wrong and it doesn`t understand the \0

Comment: @Nocs *How* do you get the string? From where? Not that it matters, because you need to find the true end of the string, then you can do e.g. `std::string s = std::string(the_actual_string, length_of_the_actual_string)`

Comment: the string UserChoice is actually what the user enters as a choice for file filtering

Comment: @Nocs Then it might be problematic to actually read that input, how would the user enter the terminator character? Escaped characters like `"\0"` are only valid in string literals in the source code, the C++ runtime library does not parse strings in any way.

Comment: Is there a way to convert then a string UserChoice = "Exe File|*.exe" and replace the "|" char with "\0" ? i tried this one too but it had the same result or maby i am doing a wrong convertion or without convertion the \0 character is treated as string inside the LPCWSTR

Comment: @Nocs Did you try e.g. [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)? Like `std::replace(std::begin(UserChoice), std::end(UserChoice), '|', '\0')`

Comment: I was converting it in different way but even with this doesn`t work.It shows all the files now and also it removed the option of files filter list in the dialog window :/ weird things :) i am not so good at c++ and i am still learning.